# Handling deep-linking via a web link in Xamarin for Android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, deep-linking

I need to handle a deep-link in my Xamarin application which will come from a mail.
I managed to make it works on Android and IOS but I still have a trouble with Android.

As said in [this blog](https://blog.xamarin.com/deep-link-content-with-xamarin-forms-url-navigation/) i overrode the OnAppLinkRequestReceived method to handle the navigation.

The problem is that this method is triggered once per instance of the App.

For example, if i click on the link the first time it will go to the right page(page A) because the code I wrote is triggered, but if go to another page (Page B), then put the App on background, go to back my mails and click a second time on the link, it will just resume the App and open the page B, not the page A.

Do you have any ideas on how it can be triggered at each time i click on the link ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally used the native android behaviour for deep-linking with Intents and it works in Xamarin

Comment: can you provide sample ? . also what about ios ?